# How to set variables in a Windows batch file from a txt document

Tags: windows, batch-file

Contents of Txt file:

```
OPS OPS lastmth Jun 2015
OPS OPS currmth Jul 2015
```

I would like have variables set as:

```
var1=OPS
var2=OPS
var3=lastmth
var4=Jun 2015
```

Is there a way in Windows Batch script to set variables like this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Parsing the input, or setting the variables?

Comment: @shoover I can read the line from file but it is setting each line as variables. 
like var1 = ops ops lastmth jun 2015 . Is there a way to take assign each words separated by space in the line to variables and do the same for next line too?

Comment: So it sounds like you are having trouble with parsing the line into tokens. Try searching SO with terms like batch, parse, tokens. Or maybe this related question will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453085/windows-batch-to-read-file-and-parse-lines-into-tokens-and-variables

Comment: Presumably those get set on the first line, you then do something with them and they then get set to the values in the second line? What do you want to do with them exactly?

Comment: need to pass them to another script as variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.** This is to have `var1` to `var4` available per line (assuming the text file is called `Txt_file.txt`):

```
@echo off
set /A line=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%I in (Txt_file.txt) do (
set /A line+=1
set var1=%%I
set var2=%%J
set var3=%%K
set var4=%%L
rem at this point you have 'var1' to 'var4':
echo LINE !line!:
echo var1: !var1!
echo var2: !var2!
echo var3: !var3!
echo var4: !var4!
)
endlocal
```

At the `rem` line the variables are available. Expand them like `!var1!` rather than `%var1%` due to delayed expansion (see `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` for more information on that), because we are in the body of the `for /F` loop, means in between the parenthesis after `do ()`.
The line counter `line` is just there for illustration purposes.

Outside of the `for /F` loop, the variables contain the content of the last line of the text file.
Beyond the `setlocal`/`endlocal` block, the variables are no longer available.

So the output will be:

```
LINE 1:
var1: OPS
var2: OPS
var3: lastmth
var4: Jun 2015
LINE 2:
var1: OPS
var2: OPS
var3: currmth
var4: Jul 2015
```

---

**II.** This is to have `var1`, `var2` and so on throughout the entire text file (up to `var8` in your example):

```
@echo off
set /A cnt=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%I in (Txt_file.txt) do (
set /A cnt+=1 & set var!cnt!=%%I
set /A cnt+=1 & set var!cnt!=%%J
set /A cnt+=1 & set var!cnt!=%%K
set /A cnt+=1 & set var!cnt!=%%L
)
rem at this point you have !var1!, !var2!, etc.:
echo ALL CONTENT:
for /L %%I in (1,1,%cnt%) do (
echo var%%I: !var%%I!
)
endlocal & set cnt=%cnt%
echo TOTAL AMOUNT: %cnt%
```

Again at the `rem` line the variables are available. This time I expand them by a `for /L` loop because the text file length (number of lines) could differ; the number of entries and thus the amount variables is stored in `%cnt%` (so you can expand the last variable by `!var%cnt%!`, means `var8` in our situation).
You can of course expand the variables like `!var1!`, etc. instead of the `for /L` loop; this time also `%var1%`, etc. works because we are *not* in the body of the `for /F` loop. Delayed expansion is required though in order to build up the variables dynamically.

Besides `%cnt%`, the variables are no longer available beyond the `setlocal`/`endlocal` block.

The output will be:

```
ALL CONTENT:
var1: OPS
var2: OPS
var3: lastmth
var4: Jun 2015
var5: OPS
var6: OPS
var7: currmth
var8: Jul 2015
TOTAL AMOUNT: 8
```